# How to clear environment variables in launchd?

Tags: bash

Currently, I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
function clear_secrets {
  export bob=""
  export john=""
}
clear_secrets
```

And I want this bash script to run every 1 minute through launchd. However, when I set those environment variables in a bash session, they are not being cleared out after a minute. I'm assuming it's because launchd runs the script in a different session. Is there a way to have launchd affect all bash sessions?

To clarify, I want to clear some environment variables every minute in all current bash sessions. I tried this using a bash script and having launchd sourcing that bash script every minute. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: No. Please describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: I don't think you can clear a variable on a launched application since it was already exported and the context of it is already in the launched application. Unsetting the export on your current shell that previously launched the application who inherited the variables won't unset those.

Comment: Also, if you're planning to unset the export for your current session, just use `. yourscript.sh`, not `bash yourscript.sh` or `./yourscript.sh` since it would launch another bash process where the exported variables could be unset and not of the calling shell.

Comment: Each process has its own separate set of environment variables. The `export` command only exports a variable to subprocesses created by that particular shell process (and only those it spawns *after* the export command). There is no way for one shell to change the environment of another running process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
function clear_secrets {
  export bob=""
  export john=""
}
while true
do
  clear_secrets
  sleep 60
done
```

And then update /etc/bashrc (or where ever the default bashrc is for your system) to call this script. something like:

/usr/local/bin/clearSecrets &